How to handle iterators of Result<T> in Rust?
I have an iterator that returns Result<T, Err>. I currently use it like this:
for x in it {
    let xx = x?;
    ...(use xx)
}

It's OK, but I'd like to use the more elegant iterator chain idiom, but I can't. I thought about doing the following:
it
  .take_while(|x| x.is_ok())
  .map(|x| x.unwrap())
  .(whatever)

However, in this case I'd lose the error. I want to return with the error the first time I encounter it.
I have an idea how to implement it. The iterator would need new methods analogous to the current ones:

Ones that return an iterator (such as map or filter) would call next() on the iterator, if it returns Some(Ok(x)), then use x as normal, otherwise return the resulting None or error.
Ones that terminate the chain (such as for_each or collect) would return Result<Q, Err> if their original versions returned Q. They would work as normal until they encounter Some(Ok(x)) and terminate like normal when they encounter None., If they encounter an error, return it.

The question is: is there any way to do it in standard Rust, or is there a library that does this? Or maybe I have to implement it myself?

There's a start in nightly with the try_* methods although they don't do exactly what you're asking.

Note that you can simply put the take_while last and have your whatever take Result and use Result::map to process the values.

Just a note: If you're just iterating over the items then a for-loop is the idiomatic way to do it. The documentation of for_each explicitly says so, and the for-loop usually is more readable.

There is an implementation of .collect() dedicated to this use case (see the last example of its documentation).
It transforms a sequence of Results into a Result containing the sequence.
In this example, we use .map() on the sequence to have the ability to transform its elements (Results) and in the closure another .map() on the Result in order to transform the Ok variant (while propagating the potential Err).
fn main() {
    let input1: Vec<Result<i32, String>> = vec![
        Ok(10),
        Ok(20),
        Ok(30),
        Ok(40),
        Ok(50),
        Ok(60),
        Ok(70),
        Ok(80),
    ];
    let output1: Result<Vec<i32>, String> =
        input1.into_iter().map(|r| r.map(|i| i + i / 10)).collect();
    println!("output1: {:?}", output1);
    //
    let input2: Vec<Result<i32, String>> = vec![
        Ok(10),
        Ok(20),
        Ok(30),
        Ok(40),
        Err("not 50!".to_owned()),
        Ok(60),
        Err("not 70!".to_owned()),
        Ok(80),
    ];
    let output2: Result<Vec<i32>, String> =
        input2.into_iter().map(|r| r.map(|i| i + i / 10)).collect();
    println!("output2: {:?}", output2);
}
/*
output1: Ok([11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88])
output2: Err("not 50!")
*/


It works, but it's rather clunky. collect is convenient, but as you wrote, I have to add another layer of lambda. Similarly, filter would look like something like filter(|r| r.map_or(true, |i| foo(i)). This would really need a library.

Building on prog-fh's solution.
Not what you ask for, but in case that, you want to perform all task (e.g. some IO task) before returning, you can fold all the value and error into two seperated Vec
let input3: Vec<Result<i32, String>> = vec![
    Ok(10),
    Ok(20),
    Ok(30),
    Ok(40),
    Err("not 50!".to_owned()),
    Ok(60),
    Err("not 70!".to_owned()),
    Ok(80),
];
let output3: (Vec<i32>,Vec<String>) = input3
    .into_iter()
    .fold((vec![], vec![]), |(mut vv, mut ve), i| {
        match i {
            Ok(v) => vv.push(v),
            Err(e) => ve.push(e),
        }
        (vv, ve)
    });
println!("output3: {:?}", output3);

output
output3: ([10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80], ["not 50!", "not 70!"])


Yes, this is not what I asked for. I want to stop at the first error, just like in the for loop at the beginning of my question.

If you want to do this, you can use partition from std, no need to reimplement the wheel by hand.

Cool, didn't know that

On stable Rust you can do this:
fn main() {
    let items: Vec<Result<i32, String>> = vec![
        Ok(10),
        Ok(20),
        Ok(30),
        Ok(40),
        Err("not 50!".to_owned()),
        Ok(60),
        Err("not 70!".to_owned()),
        Ok(80),
    ];

    if let Err(error) = items
        .into_iter()
        .try_for_each(|item| item.map(|item| println!("{item}")))
    {
        eprintln!("Error during iteration: {error}");
    }
}

Playground
